# how to check if the tooltip image is out of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if the tooltip image is out of the screen. i want if the image is out of the screen then the tooltip image should be of left side or right side, it should not go out of the screenand make scroll bar. here is the jquery code.

```
 this.imagePreview = function(){    
/* CONFIG */

    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 30;

    // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
    // you might want to adjust to get the right result

/* END CONFIG */
$("a.preview").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;    
    $("#preview").remove();
}); 
$("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});         
    };


  // starting the script on page load
   $(document).ready(function(){
  imagePreview();
  });
```

here is the demo code. **http://jsfiddle.net/uVXTf/1/** . note its show scroll when tooltip goes out of screen. i want tooltip should change position to right if it detect end of page in x position.

Comment: Consider checking out the plugin I posted, all you need to do is include it then you can do it in a few lines of code instead of loads :)

Comment: can you tell me where to use it coz i am a bit confuse using it. can you implement it ans show me it will be very nice.

Comment: Paste this source code - http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.viewport.js - into a file called `viewport.js`. Then, use `<script src="viewport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your page where you put your jQuery. Then you can use the `$('tooltipimageID:in-viewport')` - this means the the tooltip image is in the viewport (replace tooltipimageID with the actual ID)

Comment: hmmm issue is that the tooltip is comming from anchor source. its does not have an id or should i place id on the anchor?..

Comment: No, what selector are you using currently? a.preview? Use whatever selector you are currently using.

Comment: i tried but dint worked out. can you just place the code in this? and show me? 
http://jsfiddle.net/uVXTf/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30557/discussion-between-mossawir-and-zenith)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [jQuery UI's position function](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/), you can define what should happen on collisions:

From the documentation:

> collision (default: "flip")
>
> Type: String When the positioned element
> overflows the window in some direction, move it to an alternative
> position. Similar to my and at, this accepts a single value or a pair
> for horizontal/vertical, e.g., "flip", "fit", "fit flip", "fit none".
>
> "flip": Flips the element to the opposite side of the target and the
> collision detection is run again to see if it will fit. Whichever side
> allows more of the element to be visible will be used.
>
> "fit": Shift
> the element away from the edge of the window.
>
> "flipfit": First applies
> the flip logic, placing the element on whichever side allows more of
> the element to be visible. Then the fit logic is applied to ensure as
> much of the element is visible as possible.
>
> "none": Does not apply any
> collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some minor modifications to your code and you can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubjUz/

```
$("a.preview").mousemove(function (e) {

    var previewPosition = $("#preview").position().left + $("#preview").width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (previewPosition > windowWidth) {
        $("#preview").css("left", (windowWidth - $("#preview").width()) + "px");
    } else {
        $("#preview")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    }

});
```

Comment: this code works but it start jerking shaking the image as the mouse move

Comment: sorry, cant look now :(, have work, might do it in the eve, or maybe you can try and hack a bit more..